# Prevent my iOS 8 iPad actionsheet from dismissing it's parent ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios8, uiactionsheet

I believe this is an iOS8 bug, but I'm not certain. I can reproduce it easily with a simple project.

On iOS8, I present a viewcontroller modally as a form sheet, then within that formsheet I show an actionsheet.

```
- (IBAction)showActionSheet:(id)sender {
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"How can I stop the modal formsheet from being dismissed with the actionsheet?"
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive"
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Another Button",nil];

[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
// Confirmation message is specific to the filter applied
NSLog(@"clicked %d",buttonIndex);

}
```

When this actionsheet is dismissed automatically based on a user selection, it is also dismissing the viewcontroller that showed it. Interestingly enough, if you tap outside the actionsheet it is dismissed but does NOT take the viewcontroller with it.

Is there any way to workaround this? Perhaps a way to 'fake' a tap outside the actionsheet?

Here is a simple test project that demonstrates the behavior: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kecyi4egpckwn69/ActionsheetIssueTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: I am seeing this too.  Have you logged a bug with Apple?

Comment: There was already a radar opened according to the developer forums. I never resolved the issue, but it doesn't occur using the iOS8 UIAlertController directly. So I wound up switching between UIAlertController with Actionsheet setup and direct UIActionsheets.

Comment: Thanks.  I switched to UIAlertController too, but it would be nice if they fixed the bug.

Answer (score 3):

UIAlertView and UIActionSheet have been deprecated in iOS8. They are replaced with UIAlertController.

For updating existing code, the workaround I have found to work well is to replace usage of the delegate method:

```
actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

with the delegate method:

```
actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:
```

This will ensure that the alert controller is dismissed before attempting to present another view controller.

I ran into this issue anywhere I was attempting to present a modal as a result of an action sheet selection. This is a common paradigm when selecting a photo with an action sheet to ask for Camera or Photos. Using didDismissWithButtonIndex: allows for backward compatibility with iOS 7.

Moving forward you should embrace UIAlertController. Here's some reading:

- http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/
- https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is Temporary Fix. Use below code in action sheet delegate method.

```
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Which delegate method do you mean here?

Comment: clickedButtonAtIndex: in your case. In short write above code before you present any controller modally in side action sheet delegate of course.